# Is there a python function to Find a unknown value in a partially known String?

Tags: python, text-formatting

Let's say, we have a string like the amazon bestseller ranking, which goes as follows:

```
Nr. 490 in Category1 (link to the category)
Nr. 2 in Category2
Nr. 1 in Category3
Nr. 1 in Category4
```

I tried formatting it with the split and replace function, but is there an easier way to filter out the 490, 2, 1, 1, followed by their respective categories, meaning the output would be arrays like:

```
[490, Category1]
[2, Category2]
[1, Category3]
[1, Category4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a string, you can use the following `regex`:

```
import re

l = '''Nr. 490 in Category1 (link to the category)
Nr. 2 in Category2
Nr. 1 in Category3
Nr. 1 in Category4'''
```

---

```
[re.findall(r'(?:Nr. |in )(\w+)', i) for i in l.split('\n')] 

[['490', 'Category1'],
 ['2', 'Category2'],
 ['1', 'Category3'],
 ['1', 'Category4']]
```